# Adding multiple shapes to ItemsControl, not in collection

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have the following XAML code, with the ellipses moving in and out of a rectangle area. I would like to mark this area by drawing a rectangle, but I cannot find a way to draw this within the canvas, as it isn't possible to add the rectangle to my observableCollection "balloons".

```
<ItemsControl Name="IC" ItemsSource="{Binding balloons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Name="canvasWorld" Background="Blue" Width="{Binding canvasWidth}"  Height="{Binding canvasHeight}" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPos}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YPos}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Ellipse Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding color}" Stroke="{Binding colorBorder}" StrokeThickness="3">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-20" Y="-20"/>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    </Ellipse>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I have tried hierichial datatemplate, but I couldn't make it work. Ideally I would like to databind the size and location of the rectangle, but for now drawing it with static values would be a great start.

Comment: Do you want to have each balloon move in-out of a dedicate rectangle, or do you want all the balloon to share the same rectangle?

Comment: I would like all the balloons to share a rectangle. Basicly the retangle is just for the visualisation. I have balloons moving around according to wind data, and then I want to calculate how big an area the balloons are covering within a rectangle on my canvas, so all I need is to illustrate where this rectangle is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to add it with within the itemscontrol, but I achieved what I wanted by adding a canvas next to the excisting one, and adding the shape in that canvas with Canvas.Left set to a negative value.